# get information from array to input

Tags: javascript

how i get information from array and send it to input?
i have a filter, after filtering information i have 2 value (v1,v2) and 2 button - for v1 and v2. I need to do- by pressing the button v1 information from mynewvarv1 go to input whith id='one' - can you help me to write this function?
sorry for my english

```
    var myvar = [  // filter start
    {name:'v1',val1:'31',val2:'',val3:true,val4:false,val5:false,val6:false,},  
        {name:"Срочный на 91 день",val1:'91',val2:'',val3:true,val4:false,val5:false,val6:false,}, 
            {name:"v2",val1:'181',val2:'',val3:true,val4:false,val5:false,val6:false,}, 

];
   document.getElementById('filterButton').onclick = function(){
        var filter = [];
        filter.push(document.getElementById('val1').options[document.getElementById('val1').selectedIndex].value);
       filter.push(document.getElementById('val2').value);
       filter.push(rbvalue('val3')=='1');
       filter.push(rbvalue('val4')=='1');
        filter.push(rbvalue('val5')=='1');  
        var filtered_data = [];
       var data_accepted = true;
        for(i=0;i<myvar.length;i++){
          data_accepted = true;
          for(j=0;j<filter.length;j++){
            if(filter[j]!=='' && filter[j]!=myvar[i][('val'+(j+1))]){
              data_accepted = false;
            }

          }
        if(data_accepted){
           filtered_data.push(myvar[i]);
        }
   } 
function getmesseg (){
container.innerHTML = ' v1 <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>'
container.innerHTML = ' v2<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>'
    var mynewvarv1 = [  {vaal1:value="12",vaal2:'10.2',vaal3:'9',}  ];
    var mynewvarv2 = [  {vaal1:value="12",vaal2:'10.2',vaal3:'9',}  ];
//what the function this needs???
};
 function ab(){ if(filtered_data[i].name == "v1","v2") {getmesseg(); }};

       var container = document.getElementById('container');
       container.innerHTML = '';
       for(i=0;i<filtered_data.length;i++){
           container.innerHTML+=filtered_data[i].name+'<br />';

               ab();
       }
  };

function rbvalue(html_name){
    var undefined,default_value,i,rb_collection = document.getElementsByName(html_name);
    if(rb_collection!==undefined){
        default_value = rb_collection[0].value;
    }   
    for(i=0;i<rb_collection.length;i++){
        if(rb_collection[i].checked){
            return rb_collection[i].value;     
        }
    }   
    return default_value;
}// filter end
```

Comment: What type of input is it and what part of the information do want in it?

Comment: i need to get a number (12) from array like var mynewvar = [  {vaal1:value="12"] and to put it in id="txtIntRate" like this -   <form name="form1" method="post" action="FDCalculator.aspx" id="form1"> <input name="txtIntRate" id="txtIntRate" class="w150 s14 b" onkeyup="checknum('txtIntRate');" type="text">

Comment: Is there a reason you have `[{vaal1:value="12"}]` as opposed to just `[{vaal1:"12"}]` like normal JSON?

Comment: yes,sorry, it's my error, [{vaal1:"12"}] it's the correct option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use:

```
var input1 = document.getElementById("one");
input1.value = mynewvarv1[0].vaal1;
```

Comment: "one" is it name of input?

Comment: @user3127658 It's the id of the input element.

Comment: @user3127658 I can't really test it without the HTML, but I mynewvarv1 should be the name of the variable that has the data.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9M3cmymUUCDeG03VkhqaDZGeVk/edit?usp=sharing  it's arhive with this code, pleas look at this - look at line 330, this my code, which i can't do. If you open it in browser you must input summ 510000>, Term -365,Removing percent ->in the end, further in each field yes (да) and you'll see v14 and v15 - so with this must be 2 buttom, who must fill in the fields

Comment: @user3127658 Look at [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/80785095/Desktop555.zip). I put the code in getmesseg() and moved the function outside of the function that it was in. I'm not sure that it's exactly what you're looking for, but you should be able to get an idea of what you need to do.